# BSOD -> Disk Boot Failure -> Normal Start

Tags: windows-7, bsod, boot

Just finished putting together a new PC and am having a very unwelcome issue at startup.  While this doesn't happend *ever* time, it happens most of the time.

1. Computer is running normally
2. Reboot computer
3. Boots into Windows 7, but hangs on loading screen
4. BSOD error code 00007B
5. Reboot computer
6. BIOS returns "DISK BOOT FAILURE"
7. Reboot computer
8. Boots into windows boot menu:  "Launch Startup Repair/Boot Normally"
9. Choose "Boot Normally"
10. Windows 7 continues to load properly and all is well again.

Needless to say, this is a bit of an impact to my startup time.  I really don't know where to begin with this problem.  Is it the OS?  Is it the On-Board RAID controller?  Here's my setup:

- i7 950
- 8GB of RAM
- Windows 7 64-bit
- EVGA X58 SLI3 3
- SATA Disk in Raid 5, using onboard Intel ICH10R controller

UPDATED:  Intel ICH10R drivers are the latest, 8.9.0.1023

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the hard drive or it's connections. Not sure what though. I'd try a `chkdsk` ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause (after eliminating a number of false positives) appears to be my Blu-Ray ROM Drive.  After removing it from the system three days ago, I've yet to see the problem return.  It's removal also improved my boot time as it appears the drive was inducing a 5-10 second delay.

Answer (score 0):

**00007B** is typically a problem with the disk subsystem.

1. Using your Windows 7 install DVD, go into the repair console and run this from the Command Prompt:

   ```
   chkdsk c: /r
   ```
2. Double check your system board and RAID controller drivers are up to date as well as the BIOS version.
3. Unplug and reconnect all your cables for all the hard drives in case there is a loose connection.
4. Use a diagnostic CD like [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) to check each of your disks. I like to use Western Digital's "Data Lifeguard Diagnostic Tool" If you have a bad disk, replace it.
5. Another thing to consider is your antivirus solution. [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) is pretty good and won't cause these issues.

If all that fails, format and start over. The problem might be the data cables or the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the latest Intel ICHR drivers. Also I'd turn off fast boot. Sounds like something  is taking too long to initialize at bootup.